# How can I apply css style on react component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I recently got to know reactjs and had a try with it. There are plenty of components available on npm repositories I can download and use them. However, I didn't find a good way to add css on the elements inside the component. Like this one react-tabs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs. I can use it on my web page but how I can add css style on the tabs?

Comment: Can you please share the demo/live link where you want to add?

Answer (score 0):

use className or inline-style like

```
<div className='xxx'></div>
```

or

```
<div style={{color: 'black'}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `react-tabs` source code, you will see, that `Tab` component accepts `className` as a prop, so you could pass your own class name for tab HTML element. But, it's always developers responsibility to implement `className` and `style` properties logic for their components.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer to this question except that you style a component just as you would style any HTML element: using `class` or `ids` for example. This means that it depends how the component is implemented and it will require that you have a minimum knowledge of the HTML DOM tree that will be produced by your component.

In the library you provided, you can give your tab a `className` property (`className` in React define the `class` property of the produced node). As a result you can write `<Tab className="my-class" />` and use `.my-class` to style your component.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply multiple css style to a React Component.
See below bunch of code:

```
var MultipleCss = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        score: 20
    }
   },
render: function() {

  const starrate = {
    star:{
      clear: 'none',
      float: 'left',
      margin: '0px 4px 0px 0px',
      display: 'block',
      width: '15px',
      height: '15px',
      minWidth: '15px',
      padding: '0px',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      background: 'url(' + 'sprite.png' + ') no-repeat'
    },
    position:{
      backgroundPosition: '-257px -147px'
    },
    active: {
      backgroundPosition: '-235px -147px'
    }
  };
  return (
    < div>
      <label style={Object.assign({}, starrate.star, starrate.position)}> </label>
    </div>
  );
}
```

});

Suppose I want to add css(active) on label on the basis of a condition. So we can do like below:

```
<label style={Object.assign({}, starrate.star, starrate.position, this.state.score >=20 && starrate.active)}> </label>
```

So active class will be applied on label whenever state.score >=20.